# Access Jar File Externally

Tags: java, methods, jar, external

So, I have two jar files. Foo.jar, and Bar.jar.

Bar.jar has a Main.class holding

```
public class Main {
    public static String bob(){
       return "bob";
    }
}
```

And then in Foo.jar, i want to be able to access the "bob" method, without including the jar as a library or resource or anything like that.. It's just going to be a completely separate jar.. Is that even possible..?

Sorta like this

```
System.out.println(BarAsJarFile.Main.bob());
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What you mean is that you don't want to run java -cp Foo.jar:Bar.jar ? If so, why not?

Comment: It's possible.  But why do you wish to do it?  What application feature does this provide?

Comment: They can update Bar.jar, without updating Foo.jar. That way, i don't have to use it as a library, but can still reach the method. And what does "java -cp Foo.jar:Bar.jar" do..? Does that add Bar.jar as a library to Foo.jar..? or something? (I'm really new to Java)

Comment: Do you mean they can update Bar.jar *while the program is running*? If so, that is very tricky. If not, `java -cp Foo.jar:Bar.jar` should work fine.

Comment: Can someone tell me exactly what "java -cp Foo.jar:Bar.jar" does?.. and can i do

java -cp Foo.jar:Bar.jar fisc.cl.hereitis.Main to access a class in Foo.jar?

Comment: @thefiscster510: How do you start your application now? You must be setting a classpath somewhere already.

Comment: The jar file probably contains a manifest which indicate which class contains the main method, which would be the entry point for the JVM.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: *"They can update Bar.jar, without updating Foo.jar."* Umm.. OK.  Do these apps. have a GUI?  If so, [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) might be the answer.  Caveat though, I still don't really understand the question.

Comment: No, I have multiple main methods in a single jar.. for starting with different environment variables / working directories.

Comment: Sorry that the question isn't really descriptive.. It's kinda hard to explain what I'm doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you cannot set the classpath when you start the JVM (you can easily include multiple jar files that way), but it is possible to [add jar files to your classpath later programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402330/is-it-possible-to-add-to-classpath-dynamically-in-java).