# Load a class from a jar

Tags: java, classloader

I´m trying to load a class from a jar, I´m using a classLoader.

I have this parts of code for prepare the classLoader:

```
private void loadClass(){

    try{
        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile( Path);
        Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();

        URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + Path +"!/") };
        classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);


    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now I load a class, and I try to get a new instance

```
....           
           loadClass();

           Class device = classLoader.loadClass( "org.myPackage.MyClass");

           MyMotherClass Device = ( MyMotherClass) device.newInstance();
...
```

MyClass extends of MyMotherClass, and when I do classLoader.loadClass( "org.myPackage.MyClass"), the MyMotherClass it is in the classLoader. 
At the moment, all right.

now, in device.newInstance(), I get a exception. The problem is the other classes that are used by MyClass, are not in the classpath.

What can i do?

I have a another method that load all the needed classes in the classLoader, but does not work when I get the new instance.
I can not change MyClass and the others

Comment: Can you not change your classpath settings in advance of starting the JVM?

Comment: Does this help you out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402330/is-it-possible-to-add-to-classpath-dynamically-in-java

Comment: @Bathsheba No, I do not know the jar has to be loaded. The name it is create in runtime

Comment: Can you be more specific about "the other classes that are used by MyClass"?  Also, is the classloader you're loading `MyClass` with different than the system classloader?

Comment: I have a lot of jars, one of a each device and I need to load only one jar.

Comment: That makes sense but doesn't answer either of my questions, which makes it difficult to help.  Taking a shot in the dark, it sounds like you're loading MyClass with a classloader that doesn't delegate back to the system classloader.  If this isn't the case, then the missing classes aren't being loaded correctly.

Comment: Give the public static method from `java.lang.Class` a try: `Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader)`. MyMotherClass Device = ( MyMotherClass) java.lang.Class.forName("org.myPackage.MyClass", true, classLoader). It shouldn't make much of a difference but just try it as a long-shot possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code I use to load a jar dynamically at run-time. I exploit reflection to circumvent the fact that you *ain't really supposed to do this* (that is, modify the class path after the JVM has started). Just change `my.proprietary.exception` to something sensible.

```
    /*
     * Adds the supplied library to java.class.path.
     * This is benign if the library is already loaded.
     */
    public static synchronized void loadLibrary(java.io.File jar) throws my.proprietary.exception
    {
        try {
            /*We are using reflection here to circumvent encapsulation; addURL is not public*/
            java.net.URLClassLoader loader = (java.net.URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            java.net.URL url = jar.toURI().toURL();
            /*Disallow if already loaded*/
            for (java.net.URL it : java.util.Arrays.asList(loader.getURLs())){
                if (it.equals(url)){
                    return;
                }
            }
            java.lang.reflect.Method method = java.net.URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{java.net.URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true); /*promote the method to public access*/
            method.invoke(loader, new Object[]{url});
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException | 
            java.lang.IllegalAccessException | 
            java.net.MalformedURLException | 
            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e){
            throw new my.proprietary.exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```