# Java runs .jar and terminate itself

Tags: java, jar

I have a file `jav1.jar`. If I run it it downloads `jav2.jar` from internet and then it starts with

```
Process sp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start javaw -jar jav2.jar");
```

What do I need to do in order to terminate `jav1.jar` but keep `jav2.jar` running?

Is it possible? I still can not do it. I dont know how to terminate `jav1.jar`.

`System.exit(0);` does nothing. When I terminate `jav2.jar` from task manager, it will also terminate `jav1.jar`.

Also If I correctly terminate `jav2.jar`, `jav1.jar` will close.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program).

Comment: Why? Why not just import `jav2.jar` into the classpath and run the classes in it?

Comment: in linux if you add "&" at the end of the command you will run the new process like asynchronously

Comment: Im not sure what you think by import into the classpath. Boris The Spider

Comment: @user3228247 I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/402570/877472) illustrates (I think) how to implement what Boris is talking about. Basically, he is  suggestion to combine both processes (your jav1 and jav2) into one process to avoid the situation you described. Your application would download the jar as you described, and then it would import all the classes from that jar into the application, and invoke whatever method is required in order to start up the jav2 stuff.

Comment: It seems i can get you throught the correct path.Please provide the full execution code after **Process sp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start javaw -jar jav2.jar");** because i want to know what are you doing with sp variable(i.e,Process class).