# Class load from absolute path

Tags: java, classloader

I have a class and I want to load that class by absolute path but I am getting ClassNotFoundException. I had been through many threads like this SO and found that it's not correct to load class from absolute path.

```
    InputStream stream = new Check().getClass().getResourceAsStream(clazz+".class");

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\deep.class"));
    byte[] array = new byte[100];
    while(stream.read(array) != -1){
        os.write(array);
    }
    os.close();
    stream.close();
    Object obj = Class.forName("D:\\deep.class").newInstance();//getting exception here
    System.out.println(obj instanceof Check);
```

Comment: `Class.forName` take as argument a fully qualified class name like `com.acme.Coyote` not a path to a class file, you will have to add `D:` to the classpath and then load the class by name

Comment: Yes I got you. But how can I solve this problem and Is it correct to load class from any arbitrary path?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402330/is-it-possible-to-add-to-classpath-dynamically-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load class in this use case

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {
       new URL(
           "file:///D:/"
       )
});

Class clazz = urlClassLoader.loadClass("deep");
```

Comment: In load class it is asking for fully qualified class name. If I am using file name "deep" then it's showing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Check

Comment: But after giving complete class name with package it is working. Can you tell why?

Comment: You just wrote class name in your question so I assumed it is just placed in default package, yes ofcourse it needs fully qualified classname, because it treats that URL as the root of the classpath while loading the class and so