# How do I Use "Multiple" SSL certificates in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, system-properties

I have an application that communicate with multiple hosts at the same time. In this case I need to use multiple keystores to establish communication with other hosts.

In this case setting the system property "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" is problematic. I found an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/why-system-setproperty-cannot-change-the-classpath-at-run-time/272062) that discusses the problem well.

Then what would be the best approach to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import multiple certificates into a single keystore.
[keytool](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)