# How the proper SSL certificate is selected from java keystore in order to be sent to corresponding endpoint in case of mutual TLS

Tags: java, ssl, kotlin, mtls

I have an HTTPS endpoint that requires a client certificate(mutual TLS). 
I have created a `keystore` using `KeyStore Explorer` tool and inserted the client certificate and private key into it(entry has an alias, that is some random string).

Then I have attached that keystore to RestTemplate and my question is the following:

How the right entry(certificate) is picked up from keystore when the call is made to a particular endpoint ? What if I have multiple certificates inserted into keystore so that each of them should be picked up only in case when request is made to an appropriate endpoint(domain).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the SSL client certificate chosen when there are multiple matching certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527426/how-is-the-ssl-client-certificate-chosen-when-there-are-multiple-matching-certif)

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining multiple public private key entries in one keystore file, then in each connector of respective public keys you need to pass the value in java as "keytoreAlias" . This way the application can distinguish which certificate to Cal based on alias mentioned.