# 2 way ssl connection client handshake failure

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslhandshakeexception

Environment- windows , java sdk 1.8 , apache http client 4.5.2 , keystore jks , trustore jks.
There is remote server , ssl connection done in both directions.
First part is trustore certifucate check done.
Keystore holds 2 chains of certificates with private keys
Second part is key store client negotiation, at this point , threw handshake there is  failure.
After investigeting by wireshark help  , problem is that wrong certificate sent back to remote server.
All debug flags are used , remote server sends tcp reset flag.
Weather wrong certificate chain deleted from keystore , handshake works.
Issue began after “wrong” certificate was updated because was expired.
Have to work with both chains

Comment: So what is your question? Seems you already found a solution.

Comment: I need to work with both chains

Comment: Then have 2 key-stores, and select which one to use when you connect. Since both seems compatible with server, *you* have to supply the selection logic.

Comment: Intersting idea , problem that it is system level client. General idea is to treat all ssl communication with one key store , not replicate it for every third party.

Comment: Then you need to [customize HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html) so you can supply the selection logic.

Comment: found same issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768843/jks-with-multiple-privatekeyentries)