# How to find current jvm classpath?

Tags: jvm, classpath

And then add a new path to it?

My box is Vista Pro and the java installation is JDK 5.0 with updater 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to set it and find it at runtime, or just in general? If at runtime, see this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/why-system-setproperty-cannot-change-the-classpath-at-run-time/1198693#1198693

Answer (score 0):

`C:> sdkTool -classpath classpath1;classpath2..`.

-or-

```
C:> set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2...
```

Copied from: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html