# About packages in java

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

Suppose there is one folder 'Product' in which I have a **product.java without main function** file
And **outside the Product folder** , there is source.java file having main function where I have declared the **object** of product.java
I will make the use of packages to call source.java

Now tell me the way to call the file :
***EXCEPT using 
1.CLASSPATH in cmd prompt
2.Without setting environment variable***

Comment: Is this homework? The actual question looks like something from a textbook, and there does not seem to be any practical problem :-)

Comment: Please, show us the file/folder structure and (part of) the source files (class declaration, package statements!). It's pretty hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to set a classpath, but you may set it with a jar's `MANIFEST.MF`.
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html

If you want to youse a Manifest you have to package your generated classes inside a JAR-Archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can package them into a jar file.
In the manifest file, you can provide your source.java as the main-class.
In main class you can access product.java as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Explained well here....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Also this discussion of dynamically changing the class path happened here - [Why can't System.setProperty() change the classpath at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/why-system-setproperty-cannot-change-the-classpath-at-run-time)