# How would I fix this classloader issue?

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

Let me start off by saying I'm not the best at Java so I may have missed something really simple...

I'm working on a plugin system and everything works perfectly fine in eclipse but not when I actually launch the applet outside of it.

I'm trying to load a `.class` file from a directory and execute it, I know why it isn't working I  just don't know what to do to solve it.

The issue is that Eclipse is referencing the applet itself in the class-path but it's not being referenced in the class-path outside of eclipse and I don't have access to `-cp` or `-classpath`, I can only launch it via a launcher designed to load the jar with a fixed class-path.

Any ideas on how I would be able to solve this issue?

**Loader Code:**

```
final ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File("C:/Plugin/Directory/").toURI().toURL() });
final Class<?> c = loader.loadClass("PluginFile");
Object s = c.newInstance();
s.getClass().getMethod("onLoad").invoke(s);
```

Plugin Code:

```
import net.plugintest.pluginsystem.*;

public class PluginFile extends ClientPlugin
{
    private String Author = "Plugin Author";
    private String Description = "Plugin Description"
    private Player p = new Player();

    @Override
    public void onLoad() 
    {
        p.talk("Testing");
    }
}
```

This problem has been driving me up the wall for a week now, I don't know what to do. :/

Comment: Use the URLClassLoader to Load the class that you want on your classpath too
refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.plugintest.pluginsystem.ClientPlugin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but try providing parent classloader to the classloader you create, eg:

```
ClassLoader parent = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// or
// ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File("C:/Plugin/Directory/").toURI().toURL() }, parent);
```

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.plugintest.pluginsystem.ClientPlugin` :/

Comment: Ahh i feel like a derp. Your answer helped me, instead of `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` i used `ClientPlugin.class.getClassLoader()` and it solved my problem. :P