# Where to store classes generated at runtime in a java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, code-generation, war

I've created a project that dynamically writes, compiles and instantiates a new java class at runtime and it works just fine when I run this on the command line or within eclipse. Ultimately my goal is to create a technology very similar to JSP; the user provides a "template" file and I translate it into a java class and instantiate that class. My problem is that I can't seem to instantiate the newly compiled class *when in the context of a web application*.

The core of my problem is that I don't know where to put my compiled classes so that I can immediately instantiate them.

Here are my goals:

1. This will be a generic tool for other developers so it can't be specific to my filesystem or my java container.
2. If the user undeploys their webapp from the container it should also remove these generated classfiles.

Here are my thoughts but I have never done anything like this before:

Do I put these generated classes into one of the existing entries of the classpath, if so which one? Should I let the user provide a path and then my library will add this path onto the classpath? Maybe they provide a path and I just use a custom class loader to read them from that path? The user already provides the path of their "templates" (ex. WEB-INF/templates) so should I put my compiled classes with the original templates? My understanding is that translated JSP files are stored in a proprietary place specific to that java container and therefore I can not follow in the footsteps of JSP files.

Ahh! I'm overwhelmed! Maybe there's an open source java library that does something similar and I can study it to determine where it puts it's generated files??

Comment: Why don't you compile your class files, jar them and place them under `WEB-INF/lib`. This place is the standard class location.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to define your own classloader and do the loading from there.

See [How do you change the CLASSPATH within Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java)