# Java import classes from jar file

Tags: java, file, class, jar

I have a Class written which imports some classes from JavaMail.
When the application runs, it downloads the file automatically and saves it in a directory called depend.
But I can't get it to import the classes from the Javamail jar I downloaded.
For Example, I have:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

At the top of the file, these classes are located in (Path to program/depend/javax.mail.jar)

Comment: Are you using an IDE?  If so, did you link the .jar to your buildpath?

Answer (score 3):

You must ensure that the `javamail.jar` file is on the `classpath`.

You can do this using `-classpath` arg or by setting the `CLASSPATH` env var.

- Here is [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) from Oracle describing `java -classpath` command line arg
- Here is [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) describing how to set `CLASSPATH` environment var.

Comment: How do I do that?, getClass().getResource(filePath) didn't work.

Comment: @user3055476 Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java

Comment: Your FilePath is about setting the path of some file *your prog* is working with. It won't help Eclipse or JVM. Classpath that you need is about where the classes you want the *JVM* to work with lies. You won't use it in your code, unless you are making plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to load classes over the network.

This can *only* be done using a `ClassLoader`. It cannot be done *any other way*.

It can be done using RMI - but that uses a `ClassLoader` internally.