# Gae backend module in android studio. What is the correct way to manage resource bundles?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, internationalization

I just can't find a way to properly set my backend module in android studio so it will read correctly my i18n properties files.

I did put names.properties and names_fr.properties in backend/src/main/java. Android Studio then properly warps it in a 'lib' folder named "Resource Bundle 'name'"

But the files are not being copied to exploded-app\WEB-INF\classes when I start the backend module in android studio...

So when, in my servlet, I try to access the bundle doing 
name = ResourceBundle.getBundle("name");

I get :
Can't find bundle for base name name, locale fr_FR

I could probably find a way to hack this arround (I did manage to read properties files from WEB-INF) but my setup is really google mainstream (android studio, gae, backend module) so I'd like to get to know the proper way to go.

There's probably something obvious I just cannot figure out...

realated post : [Android Studio - Include ResourceBundles in Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911338/android-studio-include-resourcebundles-in-module?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the .properties files in a 'classes' folder wich I created in backend/main/webapp/WEB-INF
So, I assume this is the proper way to go with Android Studio...