# android studio resourcebundle missingresourceexception

Tags: java, android, resourcebundle

I'm trying to migrate from eclipse to Android studio. After some work I got my app to build but I get a missingresourcefileexception.

I have my achievements.properties file in the src folder of my app. Which runs fine when I build and run in eclipse.

In android studio however I get the following exception:

```
04-14 21:02:09.657  16105-16152/com.bla E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 37579
Process: com.streefgames.rotatris.android, PID: 16105
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'achievements_en', key ''
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.missingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:238)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:230)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:159)
        at com.streefgames.rotatris.helpers.StringResourceManager.<init>(StringResourceManager.java:18)
```

I have tried moving my resource file around, adding resource files to make a bundle, different locales and all the other things I found. But it is still not working.
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I guess I wont migrate then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a resources folder within your src/main folder and place the properties file there. This resources folder can be created via the context menu (New > Folder > Java Resources Folder). It worked for me. I found this hint at [Android Studio - Include ResourceBundles in Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911338/android-studio-include-resourcebundles-in-module)

Comment: Note that it is also possible to simply add an existing resource folder (see my [answer at the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985134/905686)) instead of creating a new one.