# Android Studio 3.0 with Gradle 4.1 producing java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, paho

I've upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle too pointing to the latest 4.1 version, the app started reporting a Runtime Exception

> **java.util.MissingResourceException**: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat, locale en_US
>                             at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1557)
>                             at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1380)
>                             at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:770)
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:72)
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.(MqttAsyncClient.java:103)
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttConnection.connect(MqttConnection.java:289) 
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.connect(MqttService.java:357) 
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.doConnect(MqttAndroidClient.java:508) 
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.access$200(MqttAndroidClient.java:81) 
>                             at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$MyServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(MqttAndroidClient.java:154) 
>                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1634) 
>                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1663) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 3.0 with Gradle 4.1 incorporated several changes one major impacting thing is [new dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html). If your module referring any local(libs folder) jar file(s) and if that jar(s) file contains **resources**(ResourceBundles), then they are stripped from final artifact.

If it is a AAR file you can refer inside extracted_aar_file/libs/exctract_the_referred_library. Then observe Resources are removed.

To fix this, follow the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30866499/4146739). The solution is application to any jar with resources. But as it is a temporary fix, try to loose couple by creating a separate library module in your project like this [image] and refer it in the dependent module (it may be app module or some other library module) like this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':jarResourceBundleFixer')
    ...
}
```

NOTE: I faced problem with local jars from libs folder, the same problem might occur if you are referring like `implementation 'group:name.of.jar.with.resources'` But the same fix should work even in that case.