# Creating Jar and loading classes in it

Tags: java, jar

I need to create a jar and load classes inside jar using classLoader. I use following code to create folder structure inside jar.This works fine but when i try to load class from jar it throws exception ClassNotFound.

```
public void createJar() throws IOException
{
    //FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\MyFolder\\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\\webapps\\SpringTest\\WEB-INF\\lib\\serviceJar.jar");
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("D:/MyFolder/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/SpringTest/WEB-INF/lib/serviceJar.jar");
    JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(stream, new Manifest());
    add(new File("D:/myJar"), target);
    target.close();
    stream.close();
}

private void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
{

  byte buffer[] = new byte[10204];
  try
  {
    if (source.isDirectory())
    {
      String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
      if (!name.isEmpty())
      {
        if (!name.endsWith("/"))
          name += "/";
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        target.closeEntry();
      }
      for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
        add(nestedFile, target);
      return;
    }

    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
   // JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath());
    entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
    target.putNextEntry(entry);



    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
    while (true) {
      int nRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
      if (nRead <= 0)
        break;
      target.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
    }
    in.close();
    target.closeEntry();
  }
  catch(Exception e){

  }
  finally
  {

  }
}
```

Classes to be jared are at location "D:\myJar\spring\controller\MyController.class" and "
D:\myJar\spring\service\MyService.class".So jar is created as I want and also it contains folder structure(Mycontroller.class is inside jar at location \myJar\spring\controller).But when i try to load it with following code I get exception

```
public void loadJar() {
    //File root = new File("D:\\MyFolder\\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\\webapps\\SpringTest\\WEB-INF\\lib\\serviceJar.jar");//
    File root = new File("D:/MyFolder/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/SpringTest/WEB-INF/lib/serviceJar.jar");//
    URLClassLoader classLoader;
    try {

            classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });

            Class<?> cls = Class.forName("myJar.spring.controller.MyController", true, classLoader);
            Object instance = cls.newInstance(); // Should print constructor content
            System.out.println(instance);
            Method m =cls.getMethod("printThis", null);
            m.invoke(instance, null);                   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

But if I create jar without package structure inside it.It works fine.
I have checked all my paths and they are correct.Also location of class file inside Jar is correct.
Please explain why am I getting ClassNotFound Exception .Also suggest if any change is required in  createJar() or add() code.

Comment: did you checked the created jar file content?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not using the jar command to create the jar?

Comment: @Sanjeev.I have checked jar file contents.Class file exists at proper location.

Comment: @BetaRide.According to my requirement I need to create jar at runtime.Also I am asked to write a Java code to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add class-path on the go, the following link could be of help.

[How do you change the CLASSPATH within Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java)

Comment: Err, just a minor clarification: basically one the CLASSPATH cannot be changed during runtime. What you can do however, is to define custom classloaders (e.g., an URL classloader that contains the given Jar file -- don't get frightened, it's far easier than it seems :-).

Comment: @Rlegrndi.Please can you explain in detail.