# Change the Classpath of Another Java Program (Using Java)

Tags: java, classpath, external

Is there any way to change the classpath or another running Java program using Java code? Is this possible without having access to the other program's code (for example, like adding a messenger or something similar)? Something like "Reflection" except on another program?

Comment: Following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java) may give some insights on this scenario.

Comment: I have seen it already but I am not sure how to implement it to get the classloader of another process.