# Add JARs to Eclipse Plug-in Classpath during runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, classloader

I am currently writing an `Eclipse Plug-In` with dependencies to external, third-party JARs. When I configure all dependencies in the `Runtime` tab of my plug-in, everything works out fine.

[image]

However, the libraries I use may vary from installation to installation (and are themselves no plug-ins), so I would need a way to configure the classpath of my plug-in during runtime (or Eclipse start-up).

I tried loading the classes I need by using a `URLClassLoader` which works out fine. However, the third-party libraries themselves have dependencies too and do not use my `URLClassLoader` but the default class loader (which, in Eclipse, is `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader`). Setting the `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader()` did not help.

My last and desperate try was changing to `SystemClassLoader` by reflection (according to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java), but that doesn't seem to have any impact on the `Eclipse Plug-In`.

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class clazz= URLClassLoader.class;

// Use reflection
Method method= clazz.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { url });
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can either add JARs to the classpath during plug-in execution or maybe define a folder and all containing JARs will be added to the classpath automatically? Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206159/ might help

Comment: @greg-449 , I am having same requirement explained by West but the link you suggested does not solve them. any other ideas?